# "Unhandled exception"/"Access violation writing location" error with referenced array pointers

Tags: c++, function, pointers, reference

I'm trying to fill a pointer matrix with values from a text file. It's a double pointer to a simple struct with 2 ints, time and tons.

```
void get_changes(change** &c){
    ifstream file("change_data_time.prn");  //data file, time only, size is the same as tons
    string line, var;                   //string placeholders for the getlines
    int i, j;                           // count variables
    int count=0;
    while(getline(file, line))
        count++;                    //counting matrix size (matrix is square)

    c = new change *[count];    //resize pointers with matrix size
    for(i=0; i<count; i++)
        c[i] = new change[count];

    file.clear();
    file.close();
    file.open("change_data_time.prn");  //reset data stream to read values

    i = 0;  //reset counting variables
    j = 0;
    while(getline(file, line)){
        stringstream sline(line);           //getlines only read streams and output to strings
        while(getline(sline, var, '\t')){   //separate with tabs
            stringstream svar(var);
            svar >> c[i][j].time;       //BREAKS HERE
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

It breaks when i actually try to add the values to the pointer array and i can't understand why. It breaks on the first run of the while loops.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: What does `var` look like on the line before the code breaks?

Comment: Could you provide an example of what the input file looks like please?

Comment: this is the file contents, tab separated integers only
http://pastebin.com/Yi5b7VXa
but the error's gone. I used a filler int variable and did svar>>filler; c[i][j].time = filler; and it worked...

right now the problem is it only runs the inner loop once every run of the outer loop, when it should run 26 times...

Comment: the problem is that the lines in your sample file are not tab separated (not according to Visual Studio). Thus your call to getline(sline, var, '\t')) pulls the entire line into var rather than one integer at a time, and so the inner loop only runs once per iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: Completely right, they're spaces. I though it was tab delimited and it was working when playing around with vectors because the reading of each variable in each line was manual, and this needed a loop. Once i used a tab delimited txt file instead of the prn it worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would rewrite the code to get rid of the manual memory management around `change** c`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>

struct MaxtrixElement
{
    double time;
};

std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& in, MaxtrixElement& dest)
{
    double d;
    // error checking ommitted
    in >> d;
    dest.time = d;
    return in;
}

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const MaxtrixElement& e)
{
    os << e.time;
    return os;
}

typedef std::vector<MaxtrixElement> Line;
typedef std::vector<Line> Matrix;

void foobar(std::istream& is, Matrix& dest)
{
    std::string ln;
    while(std::getline(is, ln))
    {
        std::stringstream lnStream(ln);
        Line l;
        std::copy(std::istream_iterator<MaxtrixElement>(lnStream),
                  std::istream_iterator<MaxtrixElement>(),
                  std::back_inserter(l));
        dest.push_back(l);
    }
}

int main()
{
    Matrix m;
    foobar(std::cin, m);
    for(Matrix::const_iterator it=m.begin(); it!=m.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::copy(it->begin(), it->end(), std::ostream_iterator<MaxtrixElement>(std::cout, ", "));
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, i'm going to give it a try. I just started learning C/C++ and still don't know my way around vectors, so I'll look into this.

Comment: +1 - not only does this remove the need for memory management, but it also uses the STL beautifully to handle both input and output for the Matrix object. I need to write more code like this myself. :)